# RabbitMq - Should I dynamically declare queues and make one consumer listen to all queues?

Tags: rabbitmq

I have application X that can create "topics" where users can do operations, I want each "topic" to be a new "queue", so every "topic" operations are independent from another. I can create new queue on the moment of "topic" creation from this application.

What is the optimal solution for the receiving application Y - if one consumer should listen to all queues how do I create new queue dynamically while the consumer is already listening to the previous queues? Or should every queue gets its own consumer (maybe via API call to application Y to start consuming the new queue)?

Comment: There is no optimal solution if you don't specify the criteria by which it should be measured. Have you tried out your alternatives? Which one results in the clearest code? Which performs best? Which scales best? Which introduces fewest concurrency problems?

Comment: So far I don't have any working solution and I am looking for possible ideas.

Comment: Here we [go](https://www.rabbitmq.com/event-exchange.html). Use a topic to communicate about new topics

Comment: What makes you think a queue is the most appropriate tool for this rather than a database or event stream?    Topics and queues are communication infrastructure, however it sounds as if you are attempting to treat them like user data.

Comment: I am using PHP and I can't start async work or threads from the language. One alternative would be to store operations in database and have a cronjob every 10 seconds or so to see if there is new record present

Comment: PHP certainly supports asynchrony and threading.  Indeed, if threading and asynchrony weren't available, then that would also prevent you from receiving push notifications via RabbitMQ as well.  It sounds like conflating the need to use push notifications and against the semantics of the data itself.  It's unlikely that you would need more than one queue per consumer process -- that kind of user information seems like it'd make more sense being encoded inside a message;  for example, putting each message inside a 'wrapper' structure to carry metadata such as a message category.

Comment: @stubborn You have to be more specific about what your system does. You're saying "users can do operations" but are also mentioning a "receiving application Y". Is the user doing the operation and the application just reacting to it? Are there external constraints on when an operation can be processed (in other words an item dequeued) or could it be processed in a sequence as soon as it is published? Or done by the user?

Comment: The solution that I implemented is as follows - in application X users pushes to a queue (that is created as needed on the fly if it doesn't exist yet), and I have cronjob that in a given period of times sends a request to get all queues, consume all messages in the needed way and acknowledges acknowledges.

Answer (score 1):

Try out variants. Nobody here knows what's best in your specific case, and without getting your feet wet with different approaches you will also never know that.